# Zooming into the scene slowing down and stops (not in camera mode)

Tags: interface, 3d-view

Sometimes when I work in the 3d viewport, I can't zoom in or move the view up and down at a recent point. While I'm zooming in the scene it starts a kind of slowing down and stops.

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Welcome Anton! :) The link from gandalf3 should help to solve your issue. If not you can comment here or edit your question.

Comment: To summarize what's there: select a model in the area you are trying to view and press the period key(.) on the number pad of your keyboard.  This will not only zoom in but it will reset the zoom so it functions properly again.